# to generate header docs from generated code

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am a beginner in iOS development.We are trying to develop an application in xcode using objective c.We have imported the codes and libraries and builded it successfully.Now the issue is to generate header doc from generated code.For that we navigated to the generated code folder using terminal and gave the following commands:

> headerdoc2html –o GeneratedDocDir GeneratedCodeDir
>
> gatherheaderdoc GeneratedDocDir

But it generated 3 zerobytes file only.

Can anyone please help us to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your code/configuration, it is guessing only, but you should check

- existence of HeaderDoc comments / tags
- your configuration in `/$HOME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.headerDoc2HTML.config`

Comment: can i skip this step ??I am referring sybase online documents from sybaseinfocenter.com.  Next step is 'Configuring an Application to Synchronize and Retrieve MBO Data' according to that document?

Comment: @user1765037: Of course you can. But then your question states: something is not working somewhere. Without our crystal balls we won't be able to help.

Comment: To configure the application as per the document we have to register the callback first by using the following: Register the callback object by executing:

 ** 'MyCallbackHandler* theCallbackHandler = [MyCallbackHandler new]; 

[SampleApp_SampleAppDB registerCallbackHandler:theCallbackhandler];' ** In which file should we write this code? Please help...